# Parameters syntax for "ProcessBuilder.command"

Tags: java, runtime.exec

Im trying to launch a jar file as a process, the command I need to run is something like this:

"java -Xmx512M -Xms512M -jar myapp.jar args"

And this is the code I currently have working:

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder();
String[] command = {"java", "-jar", "myapp.jar"};
builder.command(command);
Process process = builder.start();

OutputStream stdin = process.getOutputStream();
InputStream stdout = process.getInputStream();

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stdout));
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(stdin));

ReaderThread rt = new ReaderThread(reader);
Thread handle = new Thread(rt, "ReaderThread");
handle.start();
```

But if I try to add something like the "-Xmx1024M" I would get a "Maximun heap error" or if I try to add the "args" in the last string then I get "Unable to access jarfile".

So what is the right syntax to add all the paramaters for the system call to be done in the right order?

Thanks a lot for your help.

EDIT:

I also tried passing the whole command but for some reason that didnt work.

Answer (score 1):

You don't appear to be handling the process's error input stream.

Please have a look here: [What to do when Runtime exec Won't](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html) which will explain the problem and give you a solution: use stream gobblers.

Comment: I do handle the streams later, but I just cant get it to execute the full command that I want. thx

Comment: I modified the original post to include that part, I can post the full code, but basically a thread reads the output, that part works I just cant pass the parameters to the sub process jar.

Comment: I use builder.redirectErrorStream(true), although is not in the post.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to set the working (aka current) directory for the process so it can find the jar file.  Or specify the classpath with -classpath so out includes that jar.

Also, do gobble the output